# handling multiple QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a parser with a main QWidget that takes a file input, and open a new QWidget and display a table with parsed data.

However, when I selected a new file from the main QWidget, it is replacing the second QWidget instead of instantiating another QWidget.

Also, I want to be able to close the main QWidget and close all QWidgets and exit the program. It is not doing that right now.

Full Code: [main.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ggullu1gs332k/main.py?dl=0)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from dbparser import DBParser
import xlsxwriter

class PopUp(QWidget):
def __init__(self, tablename, fields, rows):
    super(PopUp, self).__init__()
    #Window Property
    self.title = tablename
    self.left = 300
    self.top = 250
    self.width = 1000
    self.height = 750
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    ...

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'CMSDBParser'
    self.left = 150
    self.top = 150
    self.width = 500
    self.height = 200
    self.file = ""
    self.filepath = QLineEdit()
    self.bigEditor = QTextEdit()
    self.browse_btn = QPushButton('Browse...')
    self.parse_btn = QPushButton('Parse...')
    self.initUI()
    ...

    def parse(self):
        if self.file:
        try:
            parser = DBParser(self.file)
            dbcheck = parser.isDB()
            if dbcheck == True:
                tablename, fields, rows = parser.getData()

                self.popup = PopUp(tablename, fields, rows)
                self.popup.show()

            else:
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Warning', 'Right format but not CMS DB File')

        except:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', "Invalid File Selected \nMust be .txt or .log format")
    self.parse_btn.setEnabled(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same attribute: `self.popup` and if you create another widget it will replace it eliminating the previous window, in this case the solution is to create a list that stores the `PopUp`, on the other hand it is recommended to enable the attribute `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` making that when the `PopUp` is closed it is eliminated from the memory so that no unnecessary memory will be kept. For the case of your second requirement, an option is to overwrite the `closeEvent()` method and close the `PopUp`, but to do this you must verify if it exists since when an item is deleted from memory it does not imply that you delete its reference in the list. use `sip.isdeleted()`

```
import sip

# others imports

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        self.popups = [] # <---

    def parse(self):
        if self.file:
            try:
                parser = DBParser(self.file)
                if parser.isDB():
                    tablename, fields, rows = parser.getData()
                    popup = PopUp(tablename, fields, rows)  # <---
                    popup.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose) # <---
                    popup.show()                            # <---
                    self.popups.append(popup)               # <---
                else:
                    QMessageBox.information(self, 'Warning', 'Right format but not CMS DB File')
            except:
                QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', "Invalid File Selected \nMust be .txt or .log format")
        self.parse_btn.setEnabled(False)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for popup in self.popups:           # <---
            if not sip.isdeleted(popup):    # <---
                w.close()                   # <---
        super(App, self).closeEvent(event)
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much.